# Malay language localized app listing in Playstore not displayed

Tags: android, localization, google-play

In the Play Store Developer Console, I created an English (en-US), Indonesian (id), and Malay (ms) language app listings. 
English and Indonesian descriptions show up correctly on the Play Store, but not Malay.

When the default language on the phone is set to Bahasa Melayu, the Playstore displays the English app listing.
Has anybody seen this issue, or similar?